# c++ Boost Mix with objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, c++11, boost

I am trying to build c++ project that using boosts.
I create a objective-c++ class that using OSX-SDK-9 and I plan to us the class from normal c++ class that have boosts includes. 
The object-c++ using SDK frameworks:

```
AppKit.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
```

and it have the includes

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#include <AppKit/NSEvent.h>
```

When I add the include of the object-c++ to the boost class I see compiled errors [Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Po2kKhPKPPZkxoWlhhdDdmdlE/view?usp=sharing)
When I remove the boost include the build succeeds

The boots is compiled  in static library

Build the code with the follow parameters

```
xcode 6.3.2(6D2105)
compiler Apple LLVM6.1
GUN++11 [-std=gun++11]
libc++(LLVM c++ standard library with c++11 support)
```

What I doing wrong? 
How i can use c++ boost and OSK SDK with the same program

Comment: You can embed the image or copy and paste the error into the question to make it easier for users to get the information. Loading an external resource is just an extra step.

Comment: What's boost version? What boost header(s) do you include? What does `Collections.h` file look like? Please, show its contents. There's a name collision, but one hardly can guess where it is, without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: ...In the meanwhile, make sure you #include ObjectiveC headers *before* Boost ones, and that you don't occasionally include headers within some namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a name collision between Boost's Collection type and the Carbon Collection Manager.

"Collection" is defined in this header:

```
#include <CarbonCore/Collections.h>
```

And the symbol "Collection" is used in several places in boost.

The build log should show the exact boost header that is causing the problem. You can include a smaller subset of the boost headers to avoid the "Collection" symbol, or maybe write the functions that use boost in a separate source code file to avoid the clash.

Comment: FWIW, symbol `Collection` is used in boost only as a template argument, so *normally* it should not cause any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Including AppKit headers prior to the Boost ones solves this particular problem.

Another problem will come up - `expected unqualified-id`, it can be solved by -

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#undef nil
#include "boost headers here"
#define nil nullptr
```